# How to get all vertical space in all elements?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

What changes do I need to make to get the result like in the image?
What I want is three segments. navigation bar, left and right side. Navigation is fixed to the bottom, but the left and right side are 50% each. And all the boxes on the left side to get all possible height. 
I am using react so `style` is a litle bit different

[image]

My code looks like:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  transition: transform .6s;
}


.color {

  background-color:  rgba(58, 140, 190, 255);
}





.icon-white {
  color: white;
}

.card-text {
  color: white;

}

.title {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.418);
  font: 1.5vw sans-serif;
}
```

```html
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <div class="container-flex m-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">
            <div class="col-3">

              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h4 class=" title">LONG TEXT</h4>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">

            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                  <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                  <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                  <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around  mb-3">

            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                  <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                  <h4 class=" card-text">LONG LONG TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                  <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class=" color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
            <div>
              <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed-bottom bg-dark" style={{ height: '150px' }}>
        <h3 class="text-success">BOTTOM NAV BAR</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `vh` unit to split the screen half :

- set `50vh` to your navigation element and the "left and right side elements" row, or split the virtual height between to values like `90vh` and `10vh`, or even better if you navigation is 34px, set the top row to be `calc(100vh - 34px)`
- set `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between` in you left column element to take all the needed space. Regarding your illustration it will probably do what you want. Otherwise, set `height: 100%;` to all child rows elements for the blue boxes to fill all the space.

I will let you decide if you choose to use the bootstrap classes or custom css

Answer (score 0):

Heres the bootstrap way. Your HTML, body tag, and the div on which react is mounted will also all need `height: 100%`.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-leftpad-sxold7?file=/src/App.js:0-4551

```
    <div class="d-flex m-3 flex-column h-100">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row col overflow-auto">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">
          <div class="col-3">

            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h4 class=" title">LONG TEXT</h4>
                <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">

          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around  mb-3">

          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                <h4 class=" card-text">LONG LONG TEXT</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="h-100 color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class=" color p-3 box red" style={{ borderRadius: '5%' }}>
          <div>
            <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-dark" style={{flex: '0 0 150px'}}>
      <h3 class="text-success">BOTTOM NAV BAR</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```